# Rails timezone activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

My application.rb:

```
config.time_zone = 'Moscow'
config.time_zone = "(GMT+04:00) Moscow"
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Moscow'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

When i run this commands, i get:

```
1.9.3-p362 :001 > Time.now
 => 2013-02-14 14:18:42 +0400
1.9.3-p362 :002 > Time.zone.now
 => Thu, 14 Feb 2013 10:18:52 UTC +00:00
```

So in db i see 10:18:52 UTC +00:00.
But what and how to configure, to see such time, as in Time.Now?  (when i insert new row to db i must see time, as given by Time.now, what to configure?)

Server's time is Moscow....

also db is mysql

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use local time like this:

```
> current_time = Time.now.utc
  => 2013-02-14 15:15:58 UTC 
> current_time .localtime
  => 2013-02-14 10:15:58 -05 hours
```

You can use also:

```
Time.now.utc.in_time_zone("Moscow")
```

But for the answer to your question, the solution could be to set it like this:

```
config.time_zone = 'Moscow' (don't set this - delete this line)
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

And also you can use your local time something like this:

```
Time.local_time
```

I hope some of this approaches might help you

Comment: hm( didn't see right time( with config.time_zone = 'Moscow' 
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local

Comment: hm, try to remove config.time_zone = 'Moscow' , if you are in Moscow. It will then get the current time zone of your server - which is Moscow. Maybe this will sufficient. Let me know removing config.time_zone works. In general you can use in your model something like this: skip_time_zone_conversion_for_attributes << :startTime   , but let's wait when you test the first option.

Comment: :) the third attempt .. I don't know what exactly you are trying to accomplish, but you can use something like this Time.zone.now

Comment: I just wanna see in rails app, creater_ar of order such as server time, but not such as now...

Comment: https://makandracards.com/makandra/646-how-rails-and-mysql-are-handling-time-zones  this helps me

Answer (score 2):

In your application.rb include these lines:

```
config.time_zone = 'Moscow'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Moscow'
```

Now that you have set the time zone:

```
Time.now
=> 2013-02-14 11:14:46 +0000 
Time.current
=> Thu, 14 Feb 2013 15:14:48 MSK +04:00 
user = User.create(name: 'test')
=> #<User id: 6, name: "test", created_at: "2013-02-14 11:15:00", updated_at: "2013-02-14 11:15:00"> 
user.created_at
=> Thu, 14 Feb 2013 15:15:00 MSK +04:00
```

As you can see, despite the fact that rails stores the time as `UCT +0000` (very clever btw), the rails interface is providing the required offset. If you call any object, such as `user.created_at` it will offset the database time to return the zone time.
It is very useful, because it allows the configuration of different time zones for different users. The time will be stored without offset, but each user will get its equivalent time zone.

`Time.now` return +00:00, doesn't matter your time zone.
`Time.current` is the same as `Time.zone.now`.

Comment: where to use, what to use? give example!

Comment: it doesn't return local time for created_at ! for example server time is 14-43, but in db i see 10-43... I will not write in every controller Time.zone.now, i think that something could be configured by application.rb

Comment: i need set for all users, on all app timezone +4, and this time must set to all created field! now it doesnt

Comment: the `created_at` (or any other time) will be saved as UTC +0000, but your users will always see the time with offset, according to the zone.

Comment: now, i didn't see right time! but must... i must set one timezone for all: both user and admin